# How to stop the webhook execution when the certain condition met?

Tags: php, webhooks, razorpay

*I'm using **Razorpay API** for receiving payment and to keep track of payments, I have to use webhooks as the anti-webhook approach doesn't seem to work efficiently and effectively...*

*My question is, how to stop webhooks from executing when the order is paid...
I want to have a condition on my webhook page that **if order status == 'paid' no more webhooks execution**..Stop receiving the webhooks when order is paid...

*I'm adding commision to the user wallet, so when the order status is paid add the commision into their account and stop there...I don't want to grant commision multiple times to the same user...*

Here's what I've done so far..

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Razorpay\Api\Api;

include 'credentials.php';
$api = new Api(api_key, api_secret);

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhookBody = json_decode($json, true);
$webhookSecret='1234556777';

    try {

        $webhookSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $json, $webhookSecret);
        $api->utility->verifyWebhookSignature($json, $webhookSignature, $webhookSecret);
    
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $json);


        if($webhookBody['event'] == 'order.paid') { 
             //Grant Commission - Don't want to execute it multiple times..
         }
      
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); //Sending Status to Razorpay
  } 

    catch (SignatureVerificationError $e) {
       //Invalid Signature
    }
```

**Webhook Response**

```
{
  "entity":"event",
  "account_id":"acc_BFQ7uQEaa7j2z7",
  "event":"order.paid",
  "contains":[
    "payment",
    "order"
  ],
  "payload":{
    "payment":{
      "entity":{
        "id":"pay_DESlfW9H8K9uqM",
        "entity":"payment",
        "amount":100,
        "currency":"INR",
        "status":"captured",
        "order_id":"order_DESlLckIVRkHWj",
        "invoice_id":null,
        "international":false,
        "method":"netbanking",
        "amount_refunded":0,
        "refund_status":null,
        "captured":true,
        "description":null,
        "card_id":null,
        "bank":"HDFC",
        "wallet":null,
        "vpa":null,
        "email":"gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        "contact":"+919876543210",
        "notes":[],
        "fee":2,
        "tax":0,
        "error_code":null,
        "error_description":null,
        "created_at":1567674599
      }
    },
    "order":{
      "entity":{
        "id":"order_DESlLckIVRkHWj",
        "entity":"order",
        "amount":100,
        "amount_paid":100,
        "amount_due":0,
        "currency":"INR",
        "receipt":"rcptid #1",
        "offer_id":null,
        "status":"paid",
        "attempts":1,
        "notes":[],
        "created_at":1567674581
      }
    }
  },
  "created_at":1567674606
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the webhook would be sent repeatedly on the same transaction, even if your code has done its processing once? Is there some sort of code you are missing in the API to notify the web service that your code has handled it successfully the first time?

Comment: @GetSet Actually, webhook is not for particular user...it's general to use when any user pays the requested amount... In this case, I don't know the user's name, but I'm gettting it through webhooks response...

Comment: It would seem highly likely that the info on the particular user is included in the webhook's data sent to your server. Or at least a transaction id that you can then use to query the API for those details.

Comment: @GetSet I'd updated my question with the webhook response..

Comment: So lets say your server was down when Razorpay sends out the webhook. It makes sense that it resends because it never gets an acknowledgment from your code in some sort of timeframe. .... So my original question was perhaps you are missing some code in the "flow" where your code is supposed to acknowledge to the API that all went well in the receipt of the webhook, so that their end knows not to resend.

Comment: So, I'm sending header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); to razorpay, acknowledge them this way...

Comment: According to razorpay API :  In order to avoid an event being missed, Razorpay follows at-least-once delivery semantics. Therefore, if we have not received a successful response from your server, the Webhook is resent. There could be situations where your server accepts the event but fails to return a response in 5 seconds. In such cases, the session is marked as timeout and it is assumed that the Webhook has not been processed and therefore sent again. Hence, your server should be configured to handle or receive the same event details multiple times.

Comment: More on this:  If you were to receive the same Webhook event again, you should check for duplicates using the header_value of the header_key parameter in the request payload.   {
    "header_key":"X-Razorpay-Event-Id",
    "header_value":"DoDuorsyYeYTB0"
}

Comment: Then you'll need a db or log on your end to compare against. Or you might be able to use their db through another API call.

Comment: How can I use DB to compare against and on what condtions to compare on my end in this case when I also don't know how many time the webhook has execute..?

Comment: The `"header_value"` is unique. So once you pay commission once, store it to your db. If the same header_value is in there already, you know not to pay the commission again. ... As far as the hows on setting up the db, I'd suggest working on some code (to create context on the approach you go with) and opening a new thread on SO if you run into issues.

Comment: Yea, the same thought came to my mind, but what is `header_value` ? Where am I receiving it ?

Comment: Wasnt able to find anything on that either other than it's vague mention in the docs. Maybe it's a field that gets returned back in your original payment request. I really dont know, you can check though. .... If that's a dead end tho, possibly you could use another unique id, such as order id, or pay id.

Comment: Yea, fair enough...lets hope for the best!!!